# How to reboot a kubernetes node (vm instance) in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes

I have a GKE k8s cluster and wanted to reboot one of the nodes (a vm reboot, and not just the kubelet).

I was looking for the correct way (if there is one) than just resetting the vm directly. But I couldnt find anything in the web.

So, my plan is to use these steps:

1. drain the node
2. reboot

Is there a correct (other) way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is the correct way -- and you don't have to `drain` the Node first unless there is some extenuating circumstance. One of the major features of kubernetes is that it will route around the "damage" of having a Node disappear suddenly.

You *could* `cordon` the Node, if you wish to prevent *future* Pods from being scheduled on the soon-to-be-rebooted Node, but that's merely a time-saver, and shouldn't affect the reboot process.

Just be sure to verify the "schedulable" status of the Node after the reboot if you do use `cordon` or `drain`; I can't this very second recall whether they automatically re-register in a schedulable state.

Comment: Thank you! however, I had to uncordon the node after reboot because I drained it first.